# Web page looks different local than when it does on the server. (Development vs Production)

Tags: html, css, node.js, google-chrome, nginx

So I designed this page locally on my Mac OSX which runs on NodeJS/Express. Once I deployed and got my app running on my server and opened the page, I noticed it looked differently. I  then went on and accessed them both side by side with the same browser on the same machine and saw the differences.

For some reason the viewport (although they were the exact same) showed different values in the Dev Tools. Weird. All my elements were bigger, as if they were zoomed in. So then I decided to add zoom:0.9 to my body and after that it looked exactly the same.

I then proceeded to check all my pages to see if it was a problem with the page or with all of them and I saw that it as the same for all my pages. I could fix this by just adding zoom:0.9 to all my pages but I don't want to do that.

What is the problem?

BTW I host my website with DigitalOcean on an Ubuntu 12.04 and run it behind an Nginx reverse proxy. I am running two different apps behind Nginx

Comment: Sounds stupid but are you sure your browser window isn't zoomed in/out? (Cmd/ctrl + 0)

Comment: Yes I checked that and same zoom level for both pages.

Comment: Is it *exactly* the same code? Are you using minification tools in production? I ask this because some browsers automatically insert spaces in elements when you don't realise which will subsequently be removed when minified.

Comment: So are you saying zoom:0.9 works, but zoom:1 does not? And what about the other browsers?

Comment: @Deif It is exactly the same code. I know this because I pulled from the same git repository.

Comment: @MrLister Yes. And it is the same for all browsers unfortunately.

Comment: Yes this is happening to me. Everything is computed the same but server version just looks bigger.